# 'meteor test' not picking up *.test[s].js

Tags: unit-testing, meteor

I'm on Meteor 1.7.0.3 and want to write unittests.

I have the standard `tests/main.js` with a few tests which runs for `meteor test --driver-package meteortesting:mocha --once` from the command line.

However, code in a new file named `my.tests.js` is not picked up, no matter where I put it.

[The Meteor testing guide](https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html) explicitly states

> 2. Does eagerly load any file in our application (including in imports/ folders) that look like *.test[s].*, or *.spec[s].*

Is there some configuration that I have missed?

Comment: Do you have a small repo that can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Meteor sets

```
    "testModule": "tests/main.js"
```

in `package.json`. This defines the entry point for `meteor test`. This is why the tests in it gets run, contrary to what the testing guide indicates.

By removing this configuration, Meteor starts to behave as documented in the testing guide.